# Dodge Ram SRT-10 Problem

Tags: engine, truck, viper

My Dad owns a 2005 Ram SRT-10 Quad Cab.
The problem is when my dad trys to go over 100 MPH it doesn't let him.
And I know the Ram SRT-10 can go a lot faster than that.
In fact the Ram SRT-10 can reach speeds up to 155 MPH!

Here are some other details you might need:
Engine: An 8.3 L V10
Horse Power: 740 HP
0-60: Around 3 seconds

This is also a modded Ram SRT-10.

Comment: I don't know, @LynnCrumbling. But the answer you gave me is good. Any thing else that might be wrong?

Comment: I don't think it hits the RPM limit, @Lynn Crumbling

Comment: My Dad says it was 100 MPH, @Lynn Crumbling

Comment: Well, how do you change the governors limit, @LynnCrumbling?

Comment: I would like that to you to combine them and post, @LynnCrumbling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feels like a governor of some sort.. has it already been chipped?

If it's reliably getting to EXACTLY the same speed and maintaining it, I'd start to suspect that it was designed to be limited to that. Is it actually hitting an RPM limit, or a MPH limit? (read: how many RPMs is it doing @96MPH?)

Sounds like a built-in MPH limit. I found a [reference to a limit of 96MPH for the SRT-10](http://www.f150forum.com/f38/96mph-governor-29176/index7/), but not 100. Any chance it's actually 96? Beware, the ads on that forum is killing all of my other browser tabs.

Everything that I'm reading says that you either need a "hand tuner", or you need to send your ECU off to someone/take it into a shop and let them reprogram it.